# Call TableView:didSelectRow:AtIndexPath in viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, viewdidload

I have to select a row in my `UITableView` after the view did load.

So I did:

```
 [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop];
```

This works fine and the row is selected, *but* I also want the TableView:didSelectRow:AtIndexPath method to be called which is not the case for now.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you know the row that you are selecting, you could simply call the method that gets called in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath` directly. Or you could call the `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath` yourself:

```
NSIndexPath *initialIndex = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
[self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:initialIndex
                            animated:YES 
                      scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop];
[self tableView:self.tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:initialIndex];
```

Comment: Thank you. Nice shot. I did: `[self tableView:self.tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];` - __Works well.__

Comment: Stolen answer :) I had the same one posted 1 minute earlier :)

Comment: Sorry talfluxive, we must have been typing in parallel. It took me a bit longer to get all the code in there.

Answer (score 0):

I know it sounds stupid, but why not call it yourself? I've had the same issue with loading a view manually, and then I had to call onLoad manually as well :)

```
[self tableView:self.tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
```

not sure I got the syntax right, but you get the point

Comment: The code is wrong. `...didSelect...` is a delegate call and not a call on tableView.